# Python AWS Library Boto3: kinesis.get_records(shard_iterator)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-sqs, amazon-kinesis

I am not able to process the records that i am getting from boto3 library kinesis function **get_records(ShardIterator=shard_iterator,Limit=123)**.

The data I am getting is looks like `` b '\xe0\x01\x00\xea\xee\x01\xe4\x81\x83\xde\x01\xdf\x87\xbe\x01\xdb\x8dqldbStreamArn\x8arecordType\x87payload\x8cblockAddress\x88strandId\x8asequenceNo\x8dtransactionId\x8e\x8eblockTimestamp\x89blockHash\x8bentriesHash\x8e\x91previousBlockHash\x8e\x8fentriesHashList\x8e\x8ftransactionInfo\x8astatements\x89statement\x89startTime\x8e\x8fstatementDigest\xde\x03\xe5\x8a\x8e\xcdarn:aws:qldb:ap-southeast-1:417160253190:stream/wallet/5vHof6xwrwr2hzc2tw6HYw\x8b\x8dBLOCK_SUMMARY\x8c\xde\x03\x82\x8d\xde\x9d\x8e\x8e\x96G8ijftVQqbp6Azm3UptzGq\x8f"\x1b\xa9\x90\x8e\x96EVaGqOlkbkwB9mBuOkdKTI\x91k\x80\x0f\xe6\x83\x87\x89\x8c\x96\xc3\x01\r\x92\xae\xa0\x99R\xbe\xcba\xc5\xbc\xef\xcdd \xc2am\xc0\xb8Ro\xf3\x88\xa3tz\x94o\x8a\x98\x15`h@\x18\x93\xae\xa0\xee\xf2\x9d\xf5@*e\x13\x82 \xd5\xee\x88\x018\xc2\xc4\xa3\x15\xc9\x85 \xe7\xea\xbf\xb0\x1eU\xf0\x124w\x94\xae\xa0\x94\x1b@\x11V\x90S\xe7\x1b\x8ei\xf7\xc5\xba}\x0cJ\x10\xe9Rx\x91q\x14\x8c\x02`\x0b\xdc+\x13\xcb\x95\xbe\xc5\xae\xa0u/\xc6M\xb4\x97\xf8\xa9\xa4&1\xb7*\xb2\x17\x1dB\xc6c\x92\x9d\xcc\xecP2\r\xcf\xfa\xf8\x1f\x0f\x85\xa0\xae\xa0\xe9}\x7f\xc0>\xdf\xf5-\x8f\x9d\xa6kg\xa8\xf0\xbfHybS,\x83\xbc\x8f\xbe\x1bG\x07\xd1\xbf{:\x96\xde\x01\x87\x97\xbe\x01\x83\xde\x01\x80\x98\x8e\xcdSELECT VALUE name FROM information_schema.user_tables WHERE status = \'ACTIVE\'\x99k\x80\x0f\xe6\x83\x87\x89\x8c\x96\xc3\x00\xdd\x9a\xae\xa0\xaf\xbd\xae\x00\xbf\xb8ds\xb3\xf4\xa1\xd3tL\x9f\xe8R=\x12\xe2\xc5*\xbcwx\x98\xb1\xa37(\x1c\xcb' ``

and while doing `ion.loads(data)` getting error  `"Illegal character ó at position 1 in unknown value contained in top-level.  Pending value: bytearray(b'')"`

Please help me out to process these kind of data.

Comment: What populates the stream? You have to check what is the source of this data.

Answer (score 1):

Following the [Kinesis.Client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#Kinesis.Client.get_records) documentation you have to provide a shard iterator and after iteration of the available records can proceed with next shard iterator.

Here is a basic example of iteration of the records since some point in time:

```py
import boto3

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = boto3.client("kinesis", region_name="us-east-1")
    # It is up to you to decide how to configure shards iterator
    shard_iterator = client.get_shard_iterator(
        StreamName="demo_stream",
        ShardId="shardId-000000000001",
        ShardIteratorType="AT_TIMESTAMP",
        Timestamp=1459799926.480,
    )["ShardIterator"]

    while shard_iterator is not None:
        result = client.get_records(ShardIterator=shard_iterator)
        records = result["Records"]
        shard_iterator = result["NextShardIterator"]

        for record in records:
            print(record["Data"])
```

Check out the [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#Kinesis.Client.get_records) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like the following:

```py
base64_str = base64.b64encode(record["Data"]).decode("utf-8")

data = json.loads(decompress(base64.b64decode(data)))
```